# Centering images independent of viewport size

Tags: html, css

I have a grid of images, as I increase the size of the browser, images from row 2 jump up to row 1 as soon as space allows.

Is there any way to have the images always centered in the viewport? at the moment, the right margin increases until an image jumps up, and only at this point is it centered. I want both left and right margins to increase until between them, they can accommodate an additional image, at which point the image jumps.

For an example, see this effect on flickr.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This style may help you.

```
body 
{
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;  
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

You can change the width of a body as per your requirement.

Comment: This is not what i am after, by setting a fixed width, the number of images that can be accommodated horizontally will be constant.